# Made WordPress URL and site address URL the same

Tags: urls

When I configured my WordPress, the WordPress URL and Site Address URL were different, lets say my WordPress URL was `http://user99.com` and my site address URL was `http://user99.com/blog` but yesterday while experimenting something in *General Settings*, I made both the fields same by clearing the field meant for Site Address URL and inputting the Site Address URL as WordPress's URL.

Now all my previous posts, which were previously in the previous URL of site address were lost and when I go to that site, the it says the site can't be found. So is there any corrective action need to taken to recover my old posts?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, you need either, **phpMyAdmin** or **FTP access** to your site.

#### phpMyAdmin method

Open your database and select **wp_options** table. Locate row with
**option_name** = 'siteurl'. Click on **Edit**. In **option_value** field enter `http://user99.com`. Click **Go** button to save it.
Repeat this for **option_name** = 'home'. Exit phpMyAdmin and go to
http://user99.com/wp-admin/.

#### FTP method

Connect to your site with your favourite FTP client. Download your **wp-config.php** file. Edit this file by adding `define( 'RELOCATE', true );`
line, just before `/* That's all, stop editing! */` comment line. Save and upload it back to your site. Go to http://user99.com/wp-login.php. Login as usual. Go to Dashboard ->
Settings -> General and change **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site
Address (URL)** fields, to their correct values. Now you can remove or comment out `define( 'RELOCATE', true );` line in **wp-config.php**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your WordPress is installed in folder `blog` and when changing the site url to http://user99.com WP lost its actual path. So if can access wp-config.php and add the following two line your issue should be solved.

```
define('WP_SITEURL','http://user99.com');
define('WP_HOME','http://user99.com/blog');
```

---

**EDIT**
As Frank P. Walentynowicz corrected me this will permanently change your addresses and the standard WP settings for site url and home url will be disabled so it is better to use Frank's method for editing the Database.

Comment: You have it backwards. His 'siteurl' is `http://user99.com` and 'home' is `http://user99.com/blog`. These defines will allow him to regain access to the site, true, but this method is not recommended, because, he will not be able to edit those urls in Settings, anymore.

Comment: **Correction**: by 'These defines' I mean defines with correct urls.